# Change link color except ones under <li>s of a certain class

Tags: css

I'd like to change the link color of my blog except for the ones that are in my header menu. These items are under list items `<li>` that have a class called `menu-item`.

E.g.

```
<li id="menu-item-220" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-220"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

And in the above case, I do not want to change the link color.

This is what I am using to no avail.

```
li:not(.menu-item) a{
    color:#008acc;
}
```

Comment: that code should work, maybe you have some other style which overrides that rule applying that color

Comment: work see here:https://jsfiddle.net/gL3xtdkw/1/

Answer (score 1):

when styling anchors you should always also set colors for their pseudo classes:

```
a:link {color: blue;}
a:visited {color: purple;}
a:hover {color: red;}
a:active {color: yellow;}
```

> Link, Visited, Hover, Active
>   L, V, H, A
>   LoVe, HAte
>   https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/

I guess your links are matching default `:visited` color

Comment: `li:not(.menu-item) a` is plenty more specific to take precedence over `a:visited`

Comment: Agree, but only if no external css is used, `.menu-item` seems generic, could be part of some bootstrap-like mess